# Dovecot + Sieve - match is false when it is clearly true

Tags: email, dovecot, bug

Dovecot version 2.3.16 (7e2e900c1a)

Ok I have a problem with this:

`if address :is :domain "From" "test.net" { fileinto "INBOX/Test"; stop; }`

And the thing is that this is totally random because other domains are working perfectly fine (domain name obviously obfuscated but it doesn't change anything).

Here's debug

```
24: address test
  24:   starting `:is' match with `i;ascii-casemap' comparator:
  24:   extracting `From' headers from message
  24:   parsing address header value `"Test.Net" <sales@test.net>'
  24:   address value `sales@test.net'
  24:   extracting `domain' part from address <sales@test.net>
  24:   matching value `test.net'
  24:     with key `test.net' => 0
  24:   finishing match with result: not matched
  24: jump if result is false
  24:   jumping to line 25
```

Can somebody explain this? I have a few other cases where it is clearly a match but dovecot "decides" it is not with other domain names.

Answer (score 1):

The [examples page](https://www.fastmail.help/hc/en-us/articles/360058753794-Sieve-examples) suggest switching `:is` and `:domain`:

```
if address :domain :is "From" "test.net" { fileinto "INBOX/Test"; stop; }
```

Comment: Nope, changes nothing. Still finishing match with result: not matched

Comment: Ok I changed line number to 25 and it worked, wtf....